# MySQL query to find unmapped result

Tags: mysql

The question title is a little bit vague as I don't know how to explain it briefly.

I have 3 tables:

```
Project (projectid, name, description)
Person(personid, name, description)
ProjectPerson(projectid, personid)
```

Project and Person has a many to many relationship through ProjectPerson table

I want to create an SQL Query to find all persons that is not in any Project.

I have a solution: get all persons, get all entries in ProjectPerson and remove person entries that exist in ProjectPerson.

However it seems a little bit stupid. Could anyone advise me a better way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `left join`.  Then, check for no match in the `where` clause:

```
select p.*
from Person p left outer join
     ProjectPerson pp
     on p.personid = pp.personid
where pp.personid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on Google. Thanks for reading.

```
select * 
from Person 
where Person.personid not in (select personid from ProjectPerson)
```